# Python download image from short url by keeping its own name

Tags: python, url, filenames, urllib

I would like to download image file from shortener url or generated url which doesn't contain file name on it.

I have tried to use [content-Disposition]. However my file name is not in ASCII code. So it can't print the name.

I have found out i can use urlretrieve, request to download file but i need to save as different name.

I want to download by keeping it's own name..
How can i do this?

```
matches = re.match(expression, message, re.I)
url = matches[0]
print(url)
original = urlopen(url)
remotefile = urlopen(url)
#blah = remotefile.info()['content-Disposition']
#print(blah)
#value, params = cgi.parse_header(blah)
#filename = params["filename*"]
#print(filename)
#print(original.url)
#filename = "filedown.jpg"

#urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

These are the list that i have try but none of them work

Comment: Can you provide a sample link?

Comment: http://shorturl.at/lKOY3    <- This is the sample link

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the requests library because you can use it to get the url that the shortened url redirects to. Then, I applied your code to the redirected url and it worked. There might be a way to only use urllib (I assume thats what you are using) with this, but I dont know.

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import cgi

def getFilenameFromURL(url):
    req = requests.request("GET", url)
    # req.url is now the url the shortened url redirects to
    original = urlopen(req.url)
    value, params = cgi.parse_header(original.info()['Content-Disposition'])
    filename = params["filename*"]
    print(filename)
    return filename

getFilenameFromURL("https://shorturl.at/lKOY3")
```

You can then use urlretrieve with this. Its inefficient but it works... Also since you can get the actual url with the requests library, you can probably get the filname through there.

Comment: UTF-8''%ED%85%8C%EC%8A%A4%ED%8A%B8_test_123.PNG <- this is the result.. i can't use filename.decode('utf-8')